# If the diameters of ball bearings are normally distributed, determine the percentage with diameters between $0.610$ and $0.618$ inches.

Tags: probability

If the diameters of ball bearings are normally distributed with mean $0.6140$ inches and standard deviation
$0.0025$ inches, determine the percentage of ball bearings with diameters

1. Between $0.610$ and $0.618$ inches inclusive,
2. Greater than $0.617$
       inches,
3. Less than $0.608$ inches,
4. Equal to $0.615$ inches.

---

**My solution:**

$$\mathbb P(-1.6\leq Z\leq1.6) = 89.04\%$$ 
The book's answer was $(1)~93%$

Can someone offer some help?

Comment: The table [here](http://www.six-sigma-material.com/images/NormalDistributionTable1.GIF) gives me 2(0.9452-0.5) = 89.04% also.

Comment: @Campigone The right answer for a) is $89.04\%$, as shown below.

Comment: Looks like you found an error in the book. Not entirely uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

1. If $X$ is such that $E(X)=0.6140$ and $\sigma(X)=0.0025$, then the
   right answer is $89.04\%$. One may write $$ \begin{align}
   P(0.610<X\leq0.618)&=P\left(\frac{0.610-0.6140}{0.0025}<\frac{X-0.6140}{0.0025}\leq\frac{0.618-0.6140}{0.0025}\right)
   \\&=P\left(-1.6<Z\leq 1.6\right)
   \\&=\Pi\left(1.6\right)-\Pi\left(-1.6\right)
   \\&=2\times\Pi\left(1.6\right)-1 \\&=0.8904\cdots \end{align} $$
   giving $89.04\%$ as the right answer.
2. If $X$ is such that $E(X)=0.6140$ and $\sigma^2(X)=0.0025$, that is
   $\color{red}{\sigma(X)=0.05}$, then let's try to understand where $93\%$ could come from. One may write $$ \begin{align}
       P(0.610<X\leq0.618)&=P\left(\frac{0.610-0.6140}{0.05}<\frac{X-0.6140}{0.05}\leq\frac{0.618-0.6140}{0.05}\right)
       \\&=P\left(-0.08<Z\leq 0.08\right)
       \\&=\Pi\left(0.08\right)-\Pi\left(-0.08\right)
       \\&=2\times\Pi\left(0.08\right)-1 \\&=0.0638\cdots \end{align} $$

   and noticing that $1-0.0638=0.9362\approx \color{red}{93.6\%}$. But I don't see why this should be the answer.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is saying that the book has 93% instead of 89%.

Comment: @KennyLau I show to the OP that he is right, I explain why.

Comment: This means that the answers for the whole topic are wrong because i am having similar problems with another problem in the book

Comment: See my edit. Thanks!

Comment: my answer for part b -> 11.51% book's answer -> 8.1%, for part c-> 0.82% book's answer -> 0.47% and for part d-> 15.4% book's answer -> 15%